# Remove Administrator from domain

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I defined a domain in action to filter records based on logged user. It works fine. But i need to remove administrator from this filter, ie, administrator should see all records.

```
[('partner_type', '=', 'customer'),('user_id','=',uid)]
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can import the SUPERUSER_ID like this:

```
from odoo import SUPERUSER_ID
```

And add to your domain:

```
['|','&amp;',('partner_type', '=', 'customer'),('user_id','=',uid),('user_id', '=', SUPERUSER_ID)]
```

On xml files, you can use:

```
['|','&amp;',('partner_type', '=', 'customer'),('user_id','=',uid),('user_id', '=', 1)]
```

Just make sure the SUPERUSER_ID value is 1. You can check it on `odoo/odoo/__init__.py`

Comment: I tried you solution on xml. But after apply your solution administrator can't see anything.

Comment: The title of your question made me think you didn't want to admin to see the date. My bad. Can you try the edited answer?